Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'array') TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'array')
I am getting this error while minting the collection :-
import { createContext, useState } from 'react';
import { useAnchorWallet } from '@solana/wallet-adapter-react';
import { Connection, PublicKey, SystemProgram, Keypair } from '@solana/web3.js';
import * as anchor from '@project-serum/anchor';
import { getAssociatedTokenAddressSync } from '@solana/spl-token';
import { useWallet } from '@solana/wallet-adapter-react';
import {
    WalletMultiButton,
    WalletDisconnectButton,
} from '@solana/wallet-adapter-react-ui';
import { IDL } from '../idl';
import { Container, ButtonGroup, Button, Form } from 'react-bootstrap';
import MintCollection from './Collection';

require('@solana/wallet-adapter-react-ui/styles.css');

const ProgramContext = createContext(null);

const programID = new PublicKey(IDL.metadata.address);
const network = 'https://api.devnet.solana.com/';
const opts = { preflightCommitment: 'processed' };

const Wallet = () => {
    const wallet = useAnchorWallet();
    const { connected } = useWallet();
    console.log(connected);
    const [provider, setProvider] = useState(null);
    const [program, setProgram] = useState(null);
    const [collectionName, setCollectionName] = useState('');
    const [collectionSymbol, setCollectionSymbol] = useState('');
    const [collectionURI, setCollectionURI] = useState('');
    const [error, setError] = useState('');

    const getProvider = () => {
        if (!wallet) return null;
        const connection = new Connection(network, opts.preflightCommitment);
        return new anchor.AnchorProvider(
            connection,
            wallet,
            opts.preflightCommitment
        );
    };

    // setProvider(getProvider);

    const mintCollection = async () => {
        setError('');
        if (!connected) {
            setError('Wallet is not connected.');
            return;
        }
        const provider = getProvider();
        if (!provider) {
            setError('Provider is not available.');
            return;
        }
        // console.log(programID);
        const program = new anchor.Program(IDL, programID, provider);
        console.log(program);
        console.log("provider", provider.wallet.publicKey);
        setProgram(program);
        try {
            const collectionMintAccount = Keypair.generate();
            console.log('mint', collectionMintAccount);

            const collectionAssociatedTokenAccount =
                getAssociatedTokenAddressSync(
                    provider.wallet.publicKey,
                    collectionMintAccount.publicKey
                );

            const collectionTransactionSignature = program.methods
                .mintCollection(collectionName, collectionSymbol, collectionURI)
                .accounts({
                    payer: provider.wallet.publicKey,
                    collectionMintAccount: collectionMintAccount.publicKey,
                    collectionAssociatedTokenAccount:
                        collectionAssociatedTokenAccount,
                })

                .signers([collectionMintAccount])
                .rpc({ skipPreflight: true });

            console.log(
                'Transaction signature',
                collectionTransactionSignature
            );
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error minting collection:', error);
        }
    };

    return (
        <>
            <Container className="d-flex justify-content-center my-3">
                <ButtonGroup>
                    <div className="me-2">
                        <WalletMultiButton />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <WalletDisconnectButton />
                    </div>
                </ButtonGroup>
            </Container>
            {/* <MintCollection program={program} /> */}
            <h2>Mint Collection</h2>
            <Form>
                <Form.Group controlId="collectionName">
                    <Form.Label>Collection Name</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Enter collection name"
                        value={collectionName}
                        onChange={(e) => setCollectionName(e.target.value)}
                    />
                </Form.Group>

                <Form.Group controlId="collectionSymbol">
                    <Form.Label>Collection Symbol</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Enter collection symbol"
                        value={collectionSymbol}
                        onChange={(e) => setCollectionSymbol(e.target.value)}
                    />
                </Form.Group>

                <Form.Group controlId="collectionURI">
                    <Form.Label>Collection URI</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Enter collection URI"
                        value={collectionURI}
                        onChange={(e) => setCollectionURI(e.target.value)}
                    />
                </Form.Group>

                <Button variant="primary" onClick={mintCollection}>
                    Mint Collection
                </Button>
            </Form>

            {/* {collectionAddress && (
                <div>
                    <h3>Collection Minted!</h3>
                    <p>Collection Address: {collectionAddress}</p>
                </div>
            )} */}
        </>
    );
};

export default Wallet;

This is my IDL :-
export const IDL = {
    version: '0.1.0',
    name: 'unlimitedAuction',
    instructions: [
        {
            name: 'mint_collection',
            discriminator: [137, 138, 109, 239, 203, 207, 225, 67],
            accounts: [
                {
                    name: 'payer',
                    writable: true,
                    signer: true,
                },
                {
                    name: 'collection_metadata_account',
                    writable: true,
                    pda: {
                        seeds: [
                            {
                                kind: 'const',
                                value: [109, 101, 116, 97, 100, 97, 116, 97],
                            },
                            {
                                kind: 'account',
                                path: 'token_metadata_program',
                            },
                            {
                                kind: 'account',
                                path: 'collection_mint_account',
                            },
                        ],
                        program: {
                            kind: 'account',
                            path: 'token_metadata_program',
                        },
                    },
                },
                {
                    name: 'collection_edition_account',
                    writable: true,
                    pda: {
                        seeds: [
                            {
                                kind: 'const',
                                value: [109, 101, 116, 97, 100, 97, 116, 97],
                            },
                            {
                                kind: 'account',
                                path: 'token_metadata_program',
                            },
                            {
                                kind: 'account',
                                path: 'collection_mint_account',
                            },
                            {
                                kind: 'const',
                                value: [101, 100, 105, 116, 105, 111, 110],
                            },
                        ],
                        program: {
                            kind: 'account',
                            path: 'token_metadata_program',
                        },
                    },
                },
                {
                    name: 'collection_mint_account',
                    writable: true,
                    signer: true,
                },
                {
                    name: 'collection_associated_token_account',
                    writable: true,
                },
                {
                    name: 'token_program',
                    address: 'TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA',
                },
                {
                    name: 'token_metadata_program',
                    address: 'metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s',
                },
                {
                    name: 'associated_token_program',
                    address: 'ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL',
                },
                {
                    name: 'system_program',
                    address: '11111111111111111111111111111111',
                },
                {
                    name: 'rent',
                    address: 'SysvarRent111111111111111111111111111111111',
                },
            ],
            args: [
                {
                    name: 'collection_name',
                    type: 'string',
                },
                {
                    name: 'collection_symbol',
                    type: 'string',
                },
                {
                    name: 'collection_uri',
                    type: 'string',
                },
            ],
        },
    ],
    metadata: {
        address: 'HzkwCc34XLXCupDyzZKTu2dhgfUQe7UUY9v6Q7tRmDL4',
    },
};

This is rust program :-
#![allow(clippy::result_large_err)]

use {
    anchor_lang::prelude::*,
    anchor_spl::{
        associated_token::AssociatedToken,
        metadata::{
            create_master_edition_v3, create_metadata_accounts_v3,
            mpl_token_metadata::types::{Collection, DataV2},
            CreateMasterEditionV3, CreateMetadataAccountsV3, Metadata,
        },
        token::{mint_to, Mint, MintTo, Token, TokenAccount, Transfer},
    },
};

declare_id!("HzkwCc34XLXCupDyzZKTu2dhgfUQe7UUY9v6Q7tRmDL4");

#[program]
pub mod unlimited_auction {
    use anchor_lang::system_program;
    use anchor_spl::token;

    use super::*;

    pub fn mint_collection(
        ctx: Context<CreateCollection>,
        collection_name: String,
        collection_symbol: String,
        collection_uri: String,
    ) -> Result<()> {
        msg!("Creating collection");

        mint_to(
            CpiContext::new(
                ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
                MintTo {
                    mint: ctx.accounts.collection_mint_account.to_account_info(),
                    to: ctx
                        .accounts
                        .collection_associated_token_account
                        .to_account_info(),
                    authority: ctx.accounts.payer.to_account_info(),
                },
            ),
            1,
        )?;

        msg!("Creating metadata account");

        create_metadata_accounts_v3(
            CpiContext::new(
                ctx.accounts.token_metadata_program.to_account_info(),
                CreateMetadataAccountsV3 {
                    metadata: ctx.accounts.collection_metadata_account.to_account_info(),
                    mint: ctx.accounts.collection_mint_account.to_account_info(),
                    mint_authority: ctx.accounts.payer.to_account_info(),
                    update_authority: ctx.accounts.payer.to_account_info(),
                    payer: ctx.accounts.payer.to_account_info(),
                    system_program: ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
                    rent: ctx.accounts.rent.to_account_info(),
                },
            ),
            DataV2 {
                name: collection_name,
                symbol: collection_symbol,
                uri: collection_uri,
                seller_fee_basis_points: 0,
                creators: None,
                collection: None,
                uses: None,
            },
            false,
            true,
            None,
        )?;

        msg!("Creating master edition account");

        create_master_edition_v3(
            CpiContext::new(
                ctx.accounts.token_metadata_program.to_account_info(),
                CreateMasterEditionV3 {
                    edition: ctx.accounts.collection_edition_account.to_account_info(),
                    mint: ctx.accounts.collection_mint_account.to_account_info(),
                    update_authority: ctx.accounts.payer.to_account_info(),
                    mint_authority: ctx.accounts.payer.to_account_info(),
                    payer: ctx.accounts.payer.to_account_info(),
                    metadata: ctx.accounts.collection_metadata_account.to_account_info(),
                    token_program: ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
                    system_program: ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
                    rent: ctx.accounts.rent.to_account_info(),
                },
            ),
            None,
        )?;

        msg!("Collection has minted successfully ");

        Ok(())
    }

  
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct CreateToken<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub payer: Signer<'info>,

    /// CHECK: Validate address by deriving pda
    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds = [b"metadata", token_metadata_program.key().as_ref(), mint_account.key().as_ref()],
        bump,
        seeds::program = token_metadata_program.key(),
    )]
    pub metadata_account: UncheckedAccount<'info>,

    /// CHECK: Validate address by deriving pda
    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds = [b"metadata", token_metadata_program.key().as_ref(), mint_account.key().as_ref(), b"edition"],
        bump,
        seeds::program = token_metadata_program.key(),
    )]
    pub edition_account: UncheckedAccount<'info>,

    #[account(
        init,
        payer = payer,
        mint::decimals = 0,
        mint::authority = payer.key(),
        mint::freeze_authority = payer.key(),
    )]
    pub mint_account: Account<'info, Mint>,

    #[account(
        init_if_needed,
        payer = payer,
        associated_token::mint = mint_account,
        associated_token::authority = payer,
    )]
    pub associated_token_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,

    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    pub token_metadata_program: Program<'info, Metadata>,
    pub associated_token_program: Program<'info, AssociatedToken>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    pub rent: Sysvar<'info, Rent>,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct CreateCollection<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub payer: Signer<'info>,

    /// CHECK: Validate address by deriving pda
    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds = [b"metadata", token_metadata_program.key().as_ref(), collection_mint_account.key().as_ref()],
        bump,
        seeds::program = token_metadata_program.key(),
    )]
    pub collection_metadata_account: UncheckedAccount<'info>,

    /// CHECK: Validate address by deriving pda
    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds = [b"metadata", token_metadata_program.key().as_ref(), collection_mint_account.key().as_ref(), b"edition"],
        bump,
        seeds::program = token_metadata_program.key(),
    )]
    pub collection_edition_account: UncheckedAccount<'info>,

    #[account(
        init,
        payer = payer,
        mint::decimals = 0,
        mint::authority = payer.key(),
        mint::freeze_authority = payer.key(),
    )]
    pub collection_mint_account: Account<'info, Mint>,

    #[account(
        init_if_needed,
        payer = payer,
        associated_token::mint = collection_mint_account,
        associated_token::authority = payer,
    )]
    pub collection_associated_token_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,

    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    pub token_metadata_program: Program<'info, Metadata>,
    pub associated_token_program: Program<'info, AssociatedToken>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    pub rent: Sysvar<'info, Rent>,
}


Could you share the program code too.

@Jimii I have updated the code which have program in it. Please do check and share your thoughts on it.

Do the program tests pass? Might the error only be related to the wallet adapter or how you are doing the Program <> UI interface?

@Jimii I go the problem. The issue came with the idl. The structure of Idl was wrong.
